# Converting Date from arabic culture to english in .net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using **daterangepicker** to select date range in my application. Also i have both *english* and *arabic* versions. at the time of editing data, *english* version works fine as it is getting data in `english culture`. But in *arabic* version, date is coming as `arabic culture`, means something similar to ' 10-م 24-42-12 2018-ابريل', So the **daterangepicker** will break as it can not be converted to proper date.

How can i convert this to `english culture` in **c#** something similar to **'Apr 2018, 10-04-2018 10AM'**

Comment: " date is coming" ...coming from where? ideally, transmit your dates in something unambiguous like ISO format (e.g. yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm) and only change the format when _displaying_ . A date is never stored in a particular culture, that is merely used to set the display format to the one conventionally used by a particular cultural or linguistic group.

Comment: date is coming from DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

follow this code

```
            IFormatProvider UK = new CultureInfo("en-UK").DateTimeFormat;
            yourdate= Convert.ToDateTime(yourdate, UK);
```

OR add this before you use you datetime object

```
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-UK");
```

Comment: still giving the same result.

Comment: @sabith create new datetime variable then try to assign

Comment: created new variable, even then giving the same result